# Disposing an object after a fire and forget task has completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, dispose

I'm using a library that listens to messages by calling a method that returns a task that ends only if the a connection to the server is closed.

```
// Return a task that completes the connection ends
Task Listen();
```

The way I use listen is fire and forget, since i don't want to block on just recieving messages.

The library  also provides a subscription to execute a task when it is done sending messages (basically at the end of the listen).

```
// Exception is null if no problem occurs during processing messages
void SubscribeToOnEnd(Func<Exception, Task> OnEnd);
```

In my code, I want to be able to dispose the the library object, after the fact that listen ended, or we recieved the OnEnd.

Right now I can think of 3 options:

1. If I call it from the OnEnd task, I'm not sure of the behaviour it could cause it is the OnEnd is called from the object that I'm trying to dispose.
2. Dispose the object in the continuation of the Listen() method, but I'm not sure of the consequences of this option, any side effects as option 1.
3. Fire a task on the OnEnd using Task.Run to dispose the object. Which is don't really think is a good practice and it may cause some synchronization issues.

What is the best practice for handling such a case ?

For simplicity imagine my code as

```
public class Class
{
    private Library library;

    public async Task MyMethod(List<string> messages)
    {
        // in reality this is synchronized check
        if(this.library == null)
        {
            this.library = new Library();
            this.library.SubscribeToRecieve((m) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            });

            this.library.SubscribeToOnEnd(this.OnEnd);
            this.library.Listen();
        }


        foreach(var s in messages)
        {
            await this.library.SendAsync(s);
        }
    }

    private Task OnEnd(Exception)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

The library object is valid for use with as long as the connection is alive, and if for any reason the connection is closed/droped, I want to be able to dispose it at that point, so when MyMethod is called again I can create another object and start listening again.

Comment: I am finding some discrepancy in this code, like, why Task returned from Listen method not used, OnEnd needs to have the same signature like SubscribeToOnEnd event, which is void return and Func<Exception, Task> as input type

Comment: First, "fire-and-forget" means you don't care when the task ends, not that the task won't block. Tasks don't block by definition (unless you explicitly force them to run on the UI or parent thread). If you want to do something after a task completes, use `.ContinueWith` or `await`.